# Odoo installation ''error: [Errno 98] Address already in use''

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-10

I followed this installation guide for odoo and I get an error in the very end 
when I run odoo-bin file it gives me this error

```
teo@teo-Lenovo-Yoga-3-14:/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0$ ./odoo-bin 
2017-07-06 15:03:20,583 3754 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 10.0
2017-07-06 15:03:20,583 3754 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/teo/.local/share/Odoo/addons/10.0', u'/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/addons', u'/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/addons']
2017-07-06 15:03:20,583 3754 INFO ? odoo: database: default@default:default
2017-07-06 15:03:20,601 3754 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on 0.0.0.0:8069
Exception in thread odoo.service.httpd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/service/server.py", line 251, in http_thread
    self.httpd = ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable(self.interface, self.port, app)
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/service/server.py", line 106, in __init__
    handler=RequestHandler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 440, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, (host, int(port)), handler)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 417, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/odoo/service/server.py", line 116, in server_bind
    super(ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable, self).server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
    SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 431, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
error: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

I think it may be related to the odoo.conf file because I specify a port but it still assumes de default port 8069

this is my odoo.conf file

```
[options]

; This is the password that allows database operations:

; admin_passwd = PASSWORD

db_host = False

db_port = 8470

db_user = odoo

db_password = False

addons_path = /opt/odoo/odoo-10.0/addons

;Log Settings

logfile = /var/log/odoo/odoo.log

log_level = error
```

Does anyone have an idea of what's happening, for the record I tried to install odoo before but failed so I already had DB user created for e.g.

Comment: sorry the file is outdated db_port = 8470

Comment: stop the server and rerun. use ctrl+z for stop

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because odoo service automatically start when system starts, so you have to kill the `odoo-service` manually, and then run the `./odoo-bin` file, at which point you should be able to see odoo running again.

```
sudo pkill -9 python
```

By doing this you'll stop python from finding the odoo service `process id` and subsequently killing that process.

```
ps aux | grep odoo
sudo kill <process id>
```

There are multiple `pid` running with odoo, ending with `/etc/odoo-server.conf`, which you have to select.

I think the best option is probably

```
sudo pkill -9 python
```

All the best, I hope I solved your problem.

Comment: `sudo pkill -9 python` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

Your odoo config has another DB port set, but 8069 is the port used for xmlrpc requests. If you want to change that in config, you have to set `xmlrpc_port = 8470`.

Answer (score 2):

You getting this error because you have same port busy, you need to kill the existing process and then you can try again.

check process :

```
ps -aux|grep odoo.py

kill 09 [process id ]
```

**You can check more details of installation tutorial here using Apache2 and WSGI**  : [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0BD0YFonDE)

Answer (score 2):

For this [Errno 98] error you use following two commands:

```
root@odoo:~# ps aux | grep odoo
```

Now you getting this type code
postgres 26041  0.1  2.3 1568276 196668 ?      Sl   Sep25   5:24 python ./odoo-bin

```
root@odoo:~# sudo kill -9 26041
```

Then your error will be fix.

Answer (score 1):

[Errno 98] error you use following two commands
Get the id of the process running by following command

> root@odoo:~# `ps ax | grep servername`

Then kill the already running process

> `sudo kill -9 process_id`

Answer (score 0):

You have another process running with the 8069 port. Kill the process killing python.

With the config file in odoo, you can change to different port changing 8069 with **xmlrpc_port = 2003**.

For example:

```
[options]
; This is the password that allows database operations:
admin_passwd = admin
db_host = 0.0.0.0
db_port = 5432
db_user = randall
db_password = admin
dbfilter = odoo
addons_path = /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/addons
addons_path = /software/odoo/10.0/odoo-server/addons,/software/odoo/10.0/custom-addons,
xmlrpc_interface = 127.0.0.1
xmlrpc_port = 2002
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

If your odoo set up, it's already running when you start your ubuntu. 
It can be found in

> /etc/init.d/odoo-server

Use this command to kill the existing services

> ps -ef|grep odoo-bin
>
> sudo kill ####

Answer (score 0):

Solved with @ShivaGuntuku answer, just adding another way to solve the issue:

You're trying to run Odoo on port 8470, but as the error says you (*Address already in use*), another application is already running on that port (probably, another Odoo process).

So simply kill the process running on that port:

```
sudo fuser -k 8470/tcp
```

Then start your Odoo service again.