# Odoo Pycharm Error when running Odoo on Ubuntu

Tags: pycharm, odoo, odoo-11, odoo-12, odoo-13

Here is my Error Code when running Odoo 13 using pycharm
Please help as am new to coding and new to using python and don know what happened

```py
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/bassemwolsely/odoo/odoo-bin -c odoo-server.conf

2020-06-20 02:59:14,259 6976 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 13.0 

2020-06-20 02:59:14,259 6976 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/odoo-server.conf 

2020-06-20 02:59:14,259 6976 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/odoo/addons', '/home/bassemwolsely/.local/share/Odoo/addons/13.0', '/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/addons', '/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/my_addons'] 

2020-06-20 02:59:14,260 6976 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo13@localhost:5432 

2020-06-20 02:59:15,263 6976 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: Will use the Wkhtmltopdf binary at /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf 

Exception in thread odoo.service.httpd:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 440, in http_thread
    self.httpd = ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable(self.interface, self.port, app)
  File "/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 148, in __init__
    super(ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable, self).__init__(host, port, app,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 576, in __init__
    HTTPServer.__init__(self, get_sockaddr(host, int(port),
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 452, in __init__
    self.server_bind()
  File "/home/bassemwolsely/odoo/odoo/service/server.py", line 164, in server_bind
    super(ThreadedWSGIServerReloadable, self).server_bind()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/server.py", line 138, in server_bind
    socketserver.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 466, in server_bind
    self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use
```

Is there a solution for this ?

Comment: Try `sudo pkill -9 python`. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44952846/odoo-installation-error-errno-98-address-already-in-use/44954066

Answer (score 1):

```
lsof -i | grep 8069
```

will tell you which PID is using this port,
this one you can `kill -9 PID`

Answer (score 1):

install net-tools in your ubuntu if you have not install yet. and following this command you can solve your problem.

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

then type this command

```
netstat -pltn
```

Check PID/Program name which port are running your odoo service or python service
the type this command
***kill -9 (running PID number)***
example ***kill -9 33867*** command given bellow

```
kill -9 (your pid number)
```

the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to odoo-service or some other service already use port defined in your Odoo config so you need to kill all python operations
just type this command in terminal
`sudo pkill -9 python`
and then restart server

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when there are multiple processes running with same port.

Run below commands on the pycharm terminal:-

> ps aux | grep odoo

Then it will display various process ids. Find out the process with the port you are using with odoo and then kill all the process related to that odoo port by below command:-

> sudo kill -9 process_id

After killing the process ids restart the server.

I hope it will solve your issue.